iommu: nvidia GPU passthrough - is it working?
I think I have most of iommu-based PCI pass-through working with kvm, using freshly installed 22.04 for both host and guest.
In my guest, I've successfully installed nvidia-driver-535 and I can see the nvidia graphics card, but it doesn't seem to be the active card. Which makes me think that at least the host is passing the nvidia card through properly.
I was expecting to see a signal on the HDMI output of the graphics card, but when I connect my monitor to it, it says "no signal". Also, when connecting through the KVM spice console, the highest resolution I can set is 2560x1600, which also doesn't seem right.
Questions

I'm assuming that if the KVM guest uses the nvidia card, I'll see output on and only on the nvidia monitor output and not in the KVM spice console. Is that a valid assumption?
Can we confirm that my nvidia card is passed through properly?
If it is passed through properly, why isn't the VM using it properly/fully?

Details
This shows that its working at least somewhat:


But somehow it doesn't use the NVIDIA card (OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe):
$ inxi -G

Graphics:
  Device-1: Red Hat QXL paravirtual graphic card driver: qxl
    v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] driver: nvidia
    v: 535.171.04
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa
    gpu: qxl resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2

$ glxinfo | egrep '^Open'

OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

The Xorg.0.log looks fine to me.
Is it possibly a timing issue? When I start the VM the monitor cable is attached to the host, so there is no attached monitor on the nvidia card's HDMI output. (I need to see what I'm doing when I start the VM...)
